# SocketServer unblocks by reading 0 bytes

Tags: python, websocket, blocking, socketserver

I am implementing a websocket server and I have an issue where `rfile.read` of the module [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) sporadically will unblock when reading 0 bytes. Most times this is fine, until I start making random requests back and forth.

Here is a snipper from my code:

```
class WebSocketHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    ..
    def read_next_message(self):
        b1 = self.rfile.read(1)
        b2 = self.rfile.read(1)
        print("Length is %d %d" % (len(b1), len(b2)))
        ..
    ..
```

Correct output:

```
Length is 1 1
Length is 1 1
Length is 1 1
..
```

Occasional screw-up output:

```
Length is 0 0
(Error ..)
```

This is very weird behaviour since I would expect `self.rfile.read(1)` to unblock **ONLY** once **1 byte** has been read. Now it unblocks with **0 bytes** read. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the socket connection has been broken and there is no “EOT” (End of Transfer) sent to your server.

Answer (score 0):

[`read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) returns an empty string (length 0) on end of file.

`rfile` maps to a socket (it is obtained from `socket.makefile()`), in which case reading 0 bytes is an indication that the remote client closed the connection, or the connection has been broken for some reason.

Here is some code that demonstrates:

```
import SocketServer

class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            c = self.rfile.read(1)
            print "read %d bytes: %r" % (len(c), c)
            if len(c) == 0:
                print "end of file / socket closed"
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    port = 1234
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Run the above code and connect to the server using `nc` (or `telnet`):

```
$ nc 0.0.0.0 1234
hello
^D
```

`^D` is Ctrl-D, it closes the connection to the server. The server should emit:

```
read 1 bytes: 'h'
read 1 bytes: 'e'
read 1 bytes: 'l'
read 1 bytes: 'l'
read 1 bytes: 'o'
read 1 bytes: '\n'
read 0 bytes: ''
end of file / socket closed
```

and you can see that it is valid for `read()` to return an empty string.